# Cannot get satellite count Android

Tags: java, android, gps

I cannot seem to get the satellite count when using the geo fix command though the adb.

The geo fix help reads:

```
geo fix <longitude> <latitude> [<altitude> [<satellites>]]
allows you to send a simple GPS fix to the emulated system
The parameters are:

<longitude>   longitude, in decimal degrees
<latitude>    latitude, in decimal degrees
<altitude>    optional altitude in meters
<satellites>  number of satellites being tracked (1-12)
```

I use the following command to set the geo location to trigger OnLocationChanged to execute:

```
geo fix -106.1221 52.1311 514 5
```

In the OnlocationChanged:

```
Location newestloc = loc; 
Bundle sats = newestloc.getExtras();
int satcount = 0;
satcount = sats.getInt("satellites");
```

However whenever I call satcount, I always get 0. is the number of satellites being passed through the geo fix not counted?

Are there any other methods to getting the number satellites that are currently seen by the phone's GPS?

Edit: 
I have also tried the following code as well:

```
GpsStatus gpsstat = mlocManager.getGpsStatus(null);
Iterable sats = gpsstat.getSatellites();
Iterator satI = sats.iterator();
        int count = 0;
        while(satI.hasNext()){
            GpsSatellite gpssatellite = (GpsSatellite) satI.next();
            if (gpssatellite.usedInFix()){
            count++;
            }
        }
```

This should at minimally return 1 every time I get a fix, but it never changes from 0.

Answer (score 1):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/GpsStatus.html

try getSatellites()

What type of phone are you testing with?
Have you tried checking what lbstest mode returns? Could be that the phone itself is not picking up any satellites.

Comment: I've tried that as well.

    `int count = 0;`  
    `for (Iterator <GpsSatellite> sats = (Iterator<GpsSatellite>)   mlocManager.getGpsStatus(null).getSatellites();` `sats.hasNext();){`  
    `count++;`  
    `sats.next();`  
`}`  
`satcount = count;`  
  
The above does not work either, still returns 0.

Comment: I'm testing with a Samsung Galaxy S. But that's a side note as I mentioned that I'm trying to accomplish the count with adb. I mean it would transfer to the phone as well but if the app picked it up in adb, it should transfer over to the phone. The app is working in the sense that it picks up a gps fix and displays it on screen (tested) but it doesn't show the number of satellites that it detected.

Comment: What would I be looking for in the adb logs? I've been using adb logcat to catch errors in the code so I know where to fix them, but I don't see any changes in the log when I use the geo fix command from another command window.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a bug in Android's handling of the geo fix command in some Versions. You might want to try `geo fix -106.1221 52.1311 514 5 12`, where the number 5 is ignored on some Implementations and the 12 is taken as the number of satellites.
So the actual syntax on flawed systems would be

```
geo fix <longitude> <latitude> [<altitude> [<dummy> <satellites>]]
```